# Postfix inline regexp lookup table

Tags: email, postfix

According to the manual [regexp_table(5)](https://www.postfix.org/regexp_table.5.html) section **INLINE SPECIFICATION** there is a possibility to write the regexp lookup table inline.

> **INLINE SPECIFICATION**
>
> The contents of a table may be specified in the table name.  The  basic syntax is:
>
> ```
>    main.cf:
>        parameter = .. regexp:{ { rule-1 }, { rule-2 } .. } ..
>
>    master.cf:
>        .. -o { parameter = .. regexp:{ { rule-1 }, { rule-2 } .. } .. } ..
> ```
>
> Postfix  ignores  whitespace  after '{' and before '}', and writes each rule as one text line to an in-memory file:
>
> ```
>    in-memory file:
>        rule-1
>        rule-2
>        ..
> ```
>
> Postfix parses the result as if it is a file in /etc/postfix.
>
> Note: if a rule contains $, specify $$ to keep Postfix from  trying  to do $name expansion as it evaluates a parameter value.

I am trying to redirect all emails to my test email:

```
# main.cf
virtual_alias_maps = regexp:{ {/.*/ tester@example.com} }
```

But that just gives me an error as if this possibility never existed:

```
error: open { {/.*/ tester@example.com} }: No such file or directory
```

Did I miss something? Why is this feature not working?

Comment: You could also ask this question on the Postfix mailing list, where you will get an answer immediately.

Comment: "The contents of a table may be specified in the table name (Postfix 3.7and later)."  Are you running a recent enough postfix?